# XML Merge same name elements inside a node using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I have the following xml

```
<EMPLS>
 <EMPL>
    <NAME>110</NAME>
    <REMARK>R1</REMARK>
  </EMPL>
 <EMPL>
    <NAME>111</NAME>
    <REMARK>R1</REMARK>
    <REMARK>R2</REMARK>
    <REMARK>R3</REMARK>
  </EMPL>
</EMPLS>
```

And need to transform the xml to the following format :

```
<EMPLS>
 <EMPL>
    <NAME>110</NAME>
    <REMARK>R1</REMARK>
  </EMPL>
 <EMPL>
    <NAME>111</NAME>
    <REMARK>R1 R2 R3</REMARK>
  </EMPL>
</EMPLS>
```

I am new to xsl, could you please advise how can this be accomplished.

Comment: Both the provided source XML and the wanted transformation result are non-wellformed. Please, edit the question and correct.

Comment: Also, can you say whether you can use XSLT2.0, or just XSLT1.0? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**I This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kChildByName" match="EMPL/*"
  use="concat(generate-id(..), '+', name())"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EMPL/*" priority="0"/>

 <xsl:template match=
 "EMPL/*
     [generate-id()
     =
      generate-id(key('kChildByName',
                       concat(generate-id(..), '+', name())
                      )[1]
                  )
      ]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:for-each select="key('kChildByName',
                             concat(generate-id(..), '+', name())
                         )">
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="EMPL/*" priority="0"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document** (corrected from numerous malformities):

```
<EMPLS>
 <EMPL>
    <NAME>110</NAME>
    <REMARK>R1</REMARK>
  </EMPL>
 <EMPL>
    <NAME>111</NAME>
    <REMARK>R1</REMARK>
    <REMARK>R2</REMARK>
    <REMARK>R3</REMARK>
  </EMPL>
</EMPLS>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<EMPLS>
   <EMPL>
      <NAME>110</NAME>
      <REMARK>R1</REMARK>
   </EMPL>
   <EMPL>
      <NAME>111</NAME>
      <REMARK>R1 R2 R3</REMARK>
   </EMPL>
</EMPLS>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
2. Proper use of the **[Muenchian Grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** and composite keys.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="EMPL">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="name()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator=" "/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use of **[`<xsl:for-each-group>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#xsl-for-each-group)** .
2. Proper use of the **[`current-group()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#function-current-group)** function.

Comment: I have one doubt. In this input, it is working. Suppose input like 
<EMPL>
<NAME>111</NAME>
<REMARK>R1</REMARK>
<REMARK>R2</REMARK>
<REMARK>R3</REMARK>
<NAME>222</NAME>
<REMARK>R4</REMARK>
<REMARK>R5</REMARK>
<REMARK>R6</REMARK>
</EMPL>

Output is 
<EMPL>
<NAME>111 222</NAME>
<REMARK>R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6</REMARK>
</EMPL>

But it should be 
<EMPL>
<NAME>111</NAME>
<REMARK>R1 R2 R3</REMARK>
<NAME>222</NAME>
<REMARK>R4 R5 R6</REMARK>
</EMPL>

So please advise how can this be accomplished.

Comment: @ThirusangurajaVenkatesan, You have changed the structure of the original source XML document to your own (only a single `<EMPL>` element). Why do you expect the solution to work correctly with totally new/different structure of the XML document? In case you have a question, please *ask a question* and don't place code in comments.